# How to fix reportWebVitals is not found error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm importing reportWebVitals for React 18 App based on WebPack 5.
Here is my index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './styles.scss';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'; //error here

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And I'm getting error on import "*Can't resolve './reportWebVitals'.*"
What is the way to fix it?

Comment: Is there a file there to import from?

Answer (score 0):

create the file reportWebVitals.js and paste the following code:

```
const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry) => {
  if (onPerfEntry && onPerfEntry instanceof Function) {
    import('web-vitals').then(({ getCLS, getFID, getFCP, getLCP, getTTFB }) => {
      getCLS(onPerfEntry);
      getFID(onPerfEntry);
      getFCP(onPerfEntry);
      getLCP(onPerfEntry);
      getTTFB(onPerfEntry);
    });
  }
};

export default reportWebVitals;
```

make sure you have the dependency installed (https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-vitals)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the following lines

```
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: The question is how to fix, not remove